# What do you call the => symbol on arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

I can't seem to find the answer on google.

Comment: Don't think it have a proper name, why do you need the name of  it ?

Comment: @FabioCosta Cause our professor asked the name of that symbol. Yeah, he ask a lot of question even if it doesn't make any damn sense.

Answer (score 9):

It's called the [double arrow](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#L185).

Comment: +1: Propably the easiest way to find out: `<?php => ?>` should result int "Unexceptected T_DOUBLE_ARROW" or something similar

Comment: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DOUBLE_ARROW in [...]"